# Redirecting root context path or binding it to a servlet or mapping it with a welcome-file

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, welcome-file

I am using Jetty-9 in embedded mode and need only one web application. Consequently I would like the root URL to go to the homepage of that application, i.e. something like

```
http://localhost:4444/
```

should end up in a servlet. I start out with:

```
ServletContextHandler scContext = 
        new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
scContext.setContextPath("/");
```

None of the following worked, neither

```
scContext.addServlet(ListsServlet.class, "/");
```

nor

```
scContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"/lists})
```

where `/lists` is mapped to the `ListsServlet` servlet. All I get is a 403 (Forbidden).

I do not use the `DefaultServlet`, which seems to handle welcome files. But since the `ServletContextHandler` has `setWelcomeFiles` I expected it to contain the logic to use them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `403 Forbidden` error, you have some security setup that is not allowing you to access the handlers/servlets.

Eliminate that security (for now), verify that the rest is working, then add security a bit later to lock down specifics.

If you want to see some the suggestions below at work, consider looking at the code example in the answer from another stackoverflow: [How to correctly support html5 <video> sources with jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101463/how-to-correctly-support-html5-video-sources-with-jetty/26148582#26148582).

Welcome files are appended to the incoming request path if there is nothing present at that location.  For example requesting a directory and then a welcome-file of 'index.html' is appended to the request path.

While this would work ...

```java
scContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"lists"})

// Add Default Servlet (must be named "default")
ServletHolder holderDefault = new ServletHolder("default",DefaultServlet.class);
holderDefault.setInitParameter("resourceBase",baseDir.getAbsolutePath());
holderDefault.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
holderDefault.setInitParameter("welcomeServlets","true");
holderDefault.setInitParameter("redirectWelcome","true");

scContext.addServlet(holderDefault,"/");
```

It's likely not what you are aiming for, as you said the root path only.
The above would also make changes to requests like `/foo/` to `/foo/lists`

Instead, it might make more sense to use a Rewrite rule + handler instead of the welcome-files approach.

```java
RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();
rewrite.setHandler(scContext);

RewritePatternRule rootRule = new RewritePatternRule();
rootRule.setPattern("/");
rootRule.setReplacement("/list");
rootRule.setTerminating(true);
rewrite.addRule(rootRule);

server.setHandler(rewrite);
```

This `RewritePatternRule` simply changes any request path `/` to `/list` and then forwards that request to the wrapped `ssContext` (if you want to see the `/list` on the browser, change it to a `RedirectPatternRule` instead.

Comment: Cool, this should work, except I cannot currently verify it, because whatever I do, I get "Problem accessing /. Reason: Forbidden". Need to research how to get around it.

Comment: Wow, that was time consuming. I had a `ResourceHandler` in front of the `HandlerList` and it freaks out with "Forbidden" when it sees "/". Wrapping the `RewriteHandler` also around it helped, but I could not use a `RedirectRule` for `"/"` to `"/lists"`, because this creates a redirect loop. What works is a `RegexRedirectRule` for `^/?$`. Thanks anyway, you gave just the right hint.

Comment: @Harald I found that `RedirectPatternRule.setPattern( "" )`, as opposed to `( "/" )`,  prevents the looping.

Comment: The first approach with welcomeServlets works like a charm. Thank you!