# Retrieve Video from MySQL database HIbernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, blob

Does anyone know how to retrieve videos with type BLOB from database using Hibernate?

I saved the video using this:

```
File file = new File(videoFilePath);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session)
        .createBlob(inputStream, file.length());
course.setVideo(blob);
session.save(course);
blob.free();
```

I didn't find so much documentation online about retrieving videos. So if you know a good method, please let me know

Comment: Is for web or desktop application? are you using some framework or basic Swing / Servlet API?

Comment: It's web application, I'm using JSP and Servlets

Comment: take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101463/how-to-correctly-support-html5-video-sources-with-jetty